# Fatal error: in boostrap.inc line number 2913

Tags: views, bootstrapping

I ma facing a Fatal error It says
 `Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/myapp/myapp.com/sites/all/modules/views/modules/user/views_handler_field_user_name.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php5/lib/pear') in /home/myapp/myapp.com/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 2913`

I am unable to login,or add content type or create a view. Please help to overcome this issue.

I am very much need in it.

My site works fine if not logined.

Comment: make sure this file exists `/home/myapp/myapp.com/sites/all/modules/views/modules/user/views_handler_field_user_name.inc`

Comment: Thanks for the response @Serjas . I dint find user/views_handler_field_user_name.inc

Comment: @Serjas I have a new copy of views. In this folder i have user/views_handler_field_user_name.inc Can i simply upload to server. Will this disturb or effect my cms or previously created data ?

Comment: @serjas Why cant to post this in answer. It worked with less effort. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

[modules/user/views_handler_field_user_name.inc](http://drupalcode.org/project/views.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-3.x:/modules/user/views_handler_field_user_name.inc) is one of the Views files.
Delete the /home/myapp/myapp.com/sites/all/modules/views directory (and the files it contains), and copy the Views files from the archive file you download from the [project page](http://drupal.org/project/views). Just be sure to download the same version you installed before, and to copy the files in the same directory they were before. (The views.module file must be in /home/myapp/myapp.com/sites/all/modules/views/views.module, not /home/myapp/myapp.com/sites/all/modules/views/views/views.module, or /home/myapp/myapp.com/sites/all/modules/views.module.)

Answer (score 1):

A check list, from things that I have seen happening here:

- Does the 'includes' subdirectory exist? Is it located directly under public_html? (and not in a drupal/includes subdirectoy or anywhere else)
- Is the 'includes' subdirectory readable by the web server? (permissions at least 755, and not 700).
- Does the 'includes' subdirectory contain a 'bootstrap.inc' file? Does that file look undamaged (not zero length).
- Is the 'bootstrap.inc' file readable by the web server? (permissions at least 644, and not 600).
- Have you added any custom RewriteRules in Drupal's .htaccesss file?

Check it out more information [here](http://drupal.org/node/183293#comment-280589), I am sure this will help you..

Comment: Ok Thanks for your kindness. I will check and let you know @mohit_rocks

Comment: includes/bootstrap.inc surely exists, as it is the file where `require_once` is used. The error message says that sites/all/modules/views/modules/user/views_handler_field_user_name.inc has not been found.